# Git log, input from another command

Tags: bash, git, scripting

I have an assignment to count all the changes from all the files from a git open-source project. I know that if I use:

```
git log --pretty=oneline <filename> | wc  -l
```

I will get the number of changes of that file ( I use git bash on Windows 10)

My idea is to use

```
find .
```

and to redirect the output to the git command. How can I do the redirecting? I tried :

```
$ find . > git log --pretty=online | wc -l
0
find: unknown predicate `--pretty=online'
```

and

```
$ find . | git log --pretty=online | wc -l
fatal: invalid --pretty format: online
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do *much* better than that,

```
git log --pretty='' --name-only | sort | uniq -c
```

That's "show only the names of files changed in each commit, no other metadata, sort that list so uniq can easily count the occurrences of each'

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop over the results of `find`.

```
find -type f | grep -v '^\./\.git' |
while read f; do
    count=$(git log --oneline ${f} | wc -l)
    echo "${f} - ${count}"
done | grep -v ' 0$'
```

Your `find` is okay, but I'd restrict it to just files (`git` doesn't track directories explicitly) and remove the `.git` folder (we don't care about those files).  Pipe that into a loop (I'm using a `while`), and then your `git log` command works just fine.  Lastly, I'm going to strip anything with a count of 0, since I may have files that are part of `.gitignore` I don't want to show up (e.g., things in `__pycache__`).